# Unexpected indent Python

Tags: python

I keep getting the error "unexpected indent" for the line "lijst2 = lijst + [cat]" in the following code. I have no idea why, because as far as I can see indentation seems to be correct? Please keep in mind I am a beginner. Thank you! This is my code:

```
for fileid in corpus.fileids():
    tekst1 = corpus.words(fileid)
    instantie = defaultdict(float) 
    cat = mijn_corpus.fileids() 
    for word in tekst1:
        if word in freq: 
           instantie[word] +=1     
    for word in freq:
        if word not in tekst1:
            instantie[word] +=0
    lijst1 = [] 
    for key, value in instantie.iteritems():   
        lijst1.append(value)
        lijst2 = lijst + [cat] # Here I get the error message: unexpected indent
        resultaten.writerrow(lijst2)
```

Comment: You probably mixed spaces and tabs.

Comment: It seems that `lijst` should be `lijst1`. What if you comment that line?

Comment: From the [PEP-8 Style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) - Never mix tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mixed spaces and tabs.

The line `resultaten.writerrow(lijst2)` for example starts with a tab, while all your other lines starts with spaces (you even copied it into your question).

Better use a editor that shows such characters:

[image]

Comment: ...or an editor that changes tabs to spaces automatically